# How to check if current time falls within a specific range considering also minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a Website for Restaurants Home Delivery ,depending on Restaurant's  Home Delivery Timings i need to enable / disable Order Now Button

I have got startTime and End Time in 12 Hour format .

This is the code

```
var startTime = '8:30 AM' ;
var endTime  =  '6:30 PM' ;


var formatTime = (function () {
    function addZero(num) {
        return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
    }
    return function (dt) {
        var formatted = '';

        if (dt) {
            var hours24 = dt.getHours();
            var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
            formatted = [formatted, [addZero(hours), addZero(dt.getMinutes())].join(":"),hours24>11?"pm" :"am"].join(" ");            
        }
        return formatted;
    }
})();


var currentTime = formatTime(new Date());
```

I need to check if the current time is in between startTime and EndTime or not

If its only Hours ,i could have extracted the first character before colon from startTime ,endTime and currentTime and done a comparision like this

```
  if(currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) 
{
alert('Restaurant Open');
}
else
{
alert('Restaurant Closed');
}
```

But i need to take the minutes also in consideration ,so could you please let me how to do this comparsion if minutes were takein in consideration ??

How to check if current time falls within a specific range considering also minutes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should work

```js
var startTime = '6:30 PM';
var endTime   = '8:30 AM';
var now       = new Date();

var startDate = dateObj(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);

if (startDate > endDate) { // check if start comes before end
    var temp  = startDate; // if so, assume it's across midnight
    startDate = endDate;   // and swap the dates
    endDate   = temp;
}

var open = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'open' : 'closed'; // compare
console.log('Restaurant is ' + open);

function dateObj(d) { // date parser ...
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date  = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
    return date;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top : 0!important}
```

It splits those times and adds 12 to PM times, then creates date objects that can easily be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to work with times passing midnight, try changing the time from 6:30PM to 2:30AM.  A good solution is to use momentjs with the moment-range plugin

```
function inTimeRange(time, startTime, endTime)
{
//Setup today vars
var today = new moment(new Date());
var ayear   = today.year();
var amonth  = today.month() + 1;  // 0 to 11
var adate   = today.date();
amonth  = String(amonth).length < 2 ? "0" + amonth : amonth;
adate   = String(adate).length < 2 ? "0" + adate : adate;

//Create moment objects
var moment1, moment2;
var temp = endTime.split(" ");
if(temp[1].toLowerCase() == "am")
{
    var test1 = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + startTime;
    var test2 = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + endTime;

    //Make sure that both times aren't morning times
    if(moment(test2).isAfter(test1))
    {
        var moment1String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + startTime;
        var moment2String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + endTime;
    }
    else
    {
        var moment1String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + startTime;
        var moment2String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + (adate + 1) + " " + endTime;
    }

    moment1 = moment(moment1String,       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A");
    moment2 = moment(moment2String,       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A");
}
else 
{
    var moment1String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + startTime;
    var moment2String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + endTime;
    moment1 = moment(moment1String,       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A");
    moment2 = moment(moment2String,       "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A");
}

//Run check
var start = moment1.toDate();
var end   = moment2.toDate();

var when;
if(String(time).toLowerCase() == "now")
{
    when = moment(new Date());
}
else
{
    var timeMoment1String = ayear + "-" + amonth + "-" + adate + " " + time;
    when = moment(timeMoment1String);
}

var range = moment().range(start, end);
return when.within(range);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var startTime = '02:30 AM';
var endTime   = '13:00 PM';



var now       = new Date();
var startDate = dateObj(startTime);
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);

alert(endDate)

var open = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'open' : 'closed';
alert('Restaurant is ' + open);

function dateObj(d) {
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date  = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
    return date;
}
```

```js
var startTime = '8:30 AM';
var endTime   = '6:30 PM';

var now       = new Date();
var startDate = dateObj(startTime);
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);

var open = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'open' : 'closed';
alert('Restaurant is ' + open);

function dateObj(d) {
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date  = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to this.  My app was receiving times in military time.  So in the case where times didn't pass into the next day (i.e. start time of 09:00 and end time of 17:00 you would just check if you are between those times.

In the case of the end time being after midnight (i.e. start time of 15:00 and end time of 01:00) then there are three cases:

1. You are in a time after both start and end times, like 16:00, in which case you are inside business hours
2. You are in a time before both start and end times, like 00:30, in which case you are also inside business hours.
3. You are in a time after the end time, but before the start time, like 02:30, in which case you are outside of business hours

Here is my code sample:

```js
const isCurrentDayPart = (dayPart) => {

  let currentTime = moment();
  let startTime = moment(dayPart.startTime, "HH:mm");
  let endTime = moment(dayPart.endTime, "HH:mm");

  if (dayPart.startTime < dayPart.endTime) {
    return currentTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  } else {
    if (currentTime.isAfter(endTime) && currentTime.isAfter(startTime)) {
      return true;
    } else if (currentTime.isBefore(endTime) && currentTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```