# How can i make something happen in a time range?

Tags: javascript, time, range

I want a box to popup at 14:00. Later i want it to disappear at 16:00. How can i do this? I am using Android Studio. I want it to be something like this:

```
if (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY > 14) {
Log.d("TIME", "Time Works!");
}
```

Comment: You'll have to poll continuously and check if the poll instance is in the range you want (typically with a small buffer, such as a few seconds).  Look into `setTimeout` to kick off your poll at an interval (per minute perhaps?) then a quick logic check to see if the current time is within your range (give or take a few seconds).

Comment: I started programming apps today. I am very unexperienced. Can you please give me a code that would work? I don't find anything on the internet that does what i try to do...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with android studio and even for regular javascript all I'd be able to do is psuedocode, which doesn't tend to go over well for answers here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about Android Studio, but for JavaScript alone, you can use the `setTimeout()` function to invoke some task every X amount of time.  Set this up to check the current time every once in a while, and if it's more than 14:00 and less than 16:00, make sure your popup is shown, otherwise close it...

```
setTimeout(handlePopupVisibility, 60000);

function handlePopupVisibility() {

    var now = new Date();
    var startTime = dateObj('2:00 PM');
    var endTime = dateObj('4:00 PM');
    if (now < dateEnd && now > startTime) {
        // inside the range, show your element
        // (assumes jQuery)
        $("#popupID").show();
    } else {
        // outside the range, hide your element
        // (assumes jQuery)
        $("#popupID").hide();
    }

}

function dateObj(d) {
    var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
        date  = new Date();
    if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
    date.setHours(+parts.shift());
    date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
    return date;
}
```

(stolen from answer here: [How to check if current time falls within a specific range considering also minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078488/how-to-check-if-current-time-falls-within-a-specific-range-considering-also-minu) )