# Show an iframe only at certain hours

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there a js function that will allow me to show an iframe only during certain hours? For example, only between 7:30pm and 7:00am the next day.

Comment: Between 7:30 pm and 7:00 am in the user's timezone or in your web server's timezone? If the user opens the page at 6:59 am and the iframe is displayed, do you want it to automatically disappear a minute later, thereby confusing the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered before.  You can find it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26078488/how-to-check-if-current-time-falls-within-a-specific-range-considering-also-minu). Anyways just posting the answer.

```
var startTime = '7:00 AM';
var endTime   = '7:30 AM';
var now       = new Date();

var startDate = dateObj(startTime); // get date objects
var endDate   = dateObj(endTime);

var flag = now < endDate && now > startDate ? 'showFrame' : 'hideFrame'; // 
compare
if(flag === 'showFrame')
{
 console.log(flag);
 // show Frame
}

function dateObj(d) { // date parser ...
 var parts = d.split(/:|\s/),
 date  = new Date();
 if (parts.pop().toLowerCase() == 'pm') parts[0] = (+parts[0]) + 12;
 date.setHours(+parts.shift());
 date.setMinutes(+parts.shift());
 return date;
}
```

Fiddle : [Please see this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/av0u9yvb/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Using the following methods of the Date Object you should be able to generate the time.

```
var today = new Date()
var hour = today.getHours()
var minutes = today.getMinutes()
```

You could call on the date object every minute with `setInterval()` to find out if it is between 7:30 PM and 7:00 AM. then you could clear the interval, and set another timer to reload the iframe at 7:00 AM. where you `setInterval` again to check every minute

Please Note: `getHours()` will return the hour on a 24 hour clock so if it is 7:00 PM `today.getHours()`  outputs `19`

also there is a very useful library called moment.js that you might want to look into for JS problems involving time (seems overkill for just finding 7:30 and 7:00 though) [see here](http://momentjs.com/)